# PHP: MYSQL: Getting entries which are "hot / on the rise"

Tags: php, mysql

I´m trying to get entries from my mysql database which represent a certain "hotness". Let´s say those entries are music tracks which carry attributes like "played" (how many times this track was played) and the attribute "added" (when the track was added (in timestamp format)). I already have the category "newest", which filters for the added-attribute and the category "top" which filters for the views-attribute. Now I need the category "hot" which should combine both. I came up with this formula: hotness = views / lifetime. So if a track has been played a lot of times but added recently it might be hot. And the other way round. Does that make sense? Anyway: How can I create a sql query in php which gives me the entries which have the highest "hotness"?

My query for the top-category:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tracks ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 0,35";
```

query for new-category:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tracks ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 0,35";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like `SELECT *, (views / (now() - added)) as hotness from tracks`? You really need to make some effort before resorting to SO though.

Comment: @apokryfos I assume "from tracks"?

Comment: @tyler yes indeed

Answer (score 2):

To be really able to track the hotness, you have to have a history of when which track was played.

The total number of times a track was played and the date it was added added only allows for querying for all-time popular. The case that a track was added years ago but is getting popular now cannot be distinguished from it was added years ago, was popular back then but is not anymore.

You could add a new table where you store a date, a track ID and the number of times it was played on that date. Then you can query for all those tracks that were played a lot in the last day, 10 days and so on.